# Generate CSS or JS dynamically for a Joomla module

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-extensions

I am writing a Joomla module that includes a custom CSS stylesheet:

```
$document->addStyleSheet("modules/mod_custommenu/css/custommenu.css");
```

Now, this module needs to allow for customization of several CSS properties. I could include CSS inline in the module template, but I'd rather reference a separate file. I would like to:

1. Reference a separate CSS object (via URL)
2. Generate that CSS file using Joomla templates, like:

`.custommenu_<?php echo $module->id; ?> .menutitle {
    color: <?php echo $params->get('titlecolor'); ?>;
}`

3. If possible, cache the rendered CSS file so Joomla doesn't need to generate it everytime it is accessed.

How can I do this? Or what is the correct approach for generating ad-hoc module CSS files?

Comment: Where are the custom css choices being stored? In the database (configured by the admin) or in the session (set by the user)?

Comment: They are module parameters, coming from database. I can normally access those from templates using `$params->get("paramname");` and I'd like to do the same here.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, and I think you would want a plugin that runs right before or after the parameters are saved that would write the css file to the appropriate location.  I kind of like that idea, seems nifty.

Comment: That would work. But it's surprising that 1) Joomla doesn't provide a method to reference additional content from a module template and 2) that Joomla doesn't provide a caching facility for these matters (I don't want to manage the generated files myself, when caching is really what I'd want). Anyhow, none of this is implemented so I ended up including my styles in an ugly `<style>` block.

Comment: What are you talking about? Have you actually looked at the Joomla Framework or how people use it? Also I said use a plugin not a module though if you want to use a module you could.  Joomla has a save event you can use.  No Idea really what you mean by any of this.  WHy wouldn't you cache? Or even better store the generated file in a subfolder of /media?

Comment: Well I'm quite new to Joomla, as I said. If I save the generated CSS myself, who would delete those generated files when the module is uninstalled or new CSS files with new names are generated and old ones unreferenced? do I need to do that housekeeping myself? That's what I mean when I say I don't find a proper caching system in place for this, I haven't found an easy way to generate custom CSS from a module, but really I may be wrong, hence my question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use clearCache .. Joomla has all that stuff right there. You can see a garbage collector in the CLI folder of your installation. If you are going to write code yes you need to write all the aspects of it, it's good you are thinking about that.  What I would do is write to a folder in media and then in your uninstall script for example, just delete that folder.  JCache is super easy to use or do something else. THat's why you use a framework like joomla. I'm not sure what you mean by "proper caching" the CMS does plenty of it all the time.